# Dúvida quanto a saída de dados em Python

Tags: python, while

Estou resolvendo o seguinte exercício:

Faça um programa que imprima na tela os números de 1 a 20, um abaixo do outro. Depois modifique o programa para que ele mostre os números um ao lado do outro.

A primeira parte do enunciado eu consegui resolver, usando o loop `while` da seguinte forma:

```
x = 1
while x<=20:
    print(x)
    x +=1
```

Porém estou com dificuldade pra deixar eles na mesma linha, e não faço ideia de como resolver isso.

Comment: Já tentou concatenar os números e depois exibir esse valor concatenado? Se não sabe como fazer isso, pesquise por *concatenação* que você deve encontrar algo que elucidará uma solução para ti

Comment: Como já mencionado acima, basta fazer uma concatenação de `strings`, Por exemplo, imagine que eu diga `a = 'b' + 'c'` e depois fizer `print(a)`, ele vai printar na tela: `'bc'`

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir os números naturais começando em "1" e indo até "20", um abaixo do outro, basta utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
x = 1
while x < 21:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

**ou**

```
for c in range(1, 21):
    print(c)
```

Agora, se desejas imprimi-los um ao lado do outro, basta utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
for c in range(1, 21):
    print(c, end=' ')
print()
```

E também, se desejas imprimir os números um ao lado do outro, separados por vírgula e com um ponto final no final da sequência, podes utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
for c in range(1, 21):
    print(c, end='')
    print(', ' if c < 20 else '.', end='')
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você ja conseguiu a primeira parte, para imprimir os números um do lado do outro você pode utilizar o join:

```
print(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1,21)))
```

O `join` vai iterar sobre os elementos criando uma string única, e o print vai imprimir essa string.

Saída:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Lembrando que em python a contagem começa de 0.

Answer (score 1):

minha solução:

## programa não modificado

```
rep = 1
while rep <= 20:
 print(rep)
 rep += 1
```

## programa modificado

```
while rep <= 20:
 print(rep, end = ' ')
 rep += 1
```

também daria para criar uma def, mas não sei se você chegou a estudar isso, espero ter ajudado :)